BreakingChange - On migrating "Datadog.Tracer" package from 2.x to 3.3.1, it does not allows me to create custom span
When I have migrated the DataDog.Trace library from 2.x version to 3.3.1 version, it does not allows me to create the custom span.
Below is my code, when I run below code, it always gives me new SPAN as "Datadog.Trace.Stubs.NullSpan".
```
using Datadog.Trace;

// Start a new span
using (var scope = Tracer.Instance.StartActive("custom-operation"))
{
    // Do something
}
```

I have also gone through the DataDog release documentation, it says I need to configure "Automatic Instrumentation"

Reference Link - https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-dotnet/blob/master/docs/MIGRATING.md#migrating-from-v2xx-to-v3xx
I do not know how to configure "Automatic Instrumentation" to make it work!
Till now, I have tried adding this environment variable to enable "Automatic Instrumentation" but it did not worked.
//Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING", "xx");
//Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("CORECLR_PROFILER", "{xxxx}");
//Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH", "xxx");
//Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DD_DOTNET_TRACER_HOME", "xxx");

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!
